# How to install Ubuntu after installing Windows?

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I have three local drives, C, D and E in my Windows 8.1 installation. C drive is where Windows is installed. I've my E drive emptied. I have downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04 ISO image and created a bootable disk, and I want to install it now, without losing the Windows installation.

The last time I did this, I was unable to boot backup to Windows again - I fixed it using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). So what's the correct way to install Ubuntu *after* Windows?

Comment: It is always tricky using windows 8 with all the UEFI and BIOS and Secure Boot..etc. Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 0):

You need to create four partitions:

```
N) fs, size, mountpoint

1) ext2, 512 MB, /boot

2) ext4, at least 10 GB, /

3) ext4, at least 5 GB, /home

4) swap, 2x available RAM, none
```

Then when installing from disk, it will ask you to erase windows or install alongside. Make sure you choose "Something Else".

Then, make the partitions as described above. Remember to select the ext2 partition for bootloader installation.

After installing, use a program (in windows) such as EasyBCD and create an entry in the windows bootloader to point to the ext2 partition which, if you followed my instructions correctly, should be where GRUB is installed.

Next time you boot, you should be able to select which OS you want to boot into. I am using this setup and dual booting windows 8.1 and xubuntu 15.04 on my laptop.

Hope this helps!!!